# ASP.NET not refreshing after rebuild (running on Visual Studio for Mac Preview 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio for Mac Preview 2 to do an asp.net tutorial.

In the tutorial, it says that if I do a run without debugging attached and that I do rebuild all (cmd + shift + b) subsequently, I can just refresh (ctrl + r ) the page to see my new build (as opposed to launching a new tab everytime I want to build a new build and it's driving me nuts).

But after I do a rebuild I get this:

```
This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is it something I'm not doing right or is it something wrong with Visual Studio?

Thanks.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: i may be misremembering, but i didn't think by default your app got auto hosted again after a rebuild.  Maybe there's an extension you can grab to do so however?

Comment: @Jasen I'm following this - https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-aspnet-mvc-5-course/learn/v4/t/lecture/4853588